# javascript replace with regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to write a javascript function to format message, this is my code:

```
pattern = "{0},{1}";
args = ["hello", "world"];

pattern.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, args["$1"*1]); //$1 stands for \d+, multiply 1 to convert it to a number
```

I want the result is `hello,world`, but it is `undefined,undefined`.
so how to change it to make it correct ?

Comment: `"$1"*1` returns `NaN`. Which is not an index on the args array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
pattern.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function($0, $1){ 
   return args[$1];
});
```

Comment: what does $0, $1 mean?

Comment: @hiway $0 is just the matched string, $1 being the first match parameter. See the MDN docs for replace: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 0):

Check this <kbd>[**demo jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/89TwJ/)</kbd>

#### Regexp Patten

```
/\{(\d+)\},\{(\d+)\}/g
```

#### JavaScript

```
 pattern = "{0},{1}";
 args = ["hello", "world"];

 pattern.replace(/\{(\d+)\},\{(\d+)\}/g, args);
 //console.log(pattern.replace(/\{(\d+)\},\{(\d+)\}/g, args));
```

#### Console Result

```
hello,world
```

Comment: But this is hardcoded to two variables. @CD..'s answer handles an infinite amount of parameters